# Dynamically Running Mocha Tests

Tags: node.js, testing, mocha.js

I'm trying to run a series of tests dynamically. I have the following setup but it doesn't seem to run and I'm not getting any errors:

```
import Mocha from 'mocha';
const Test = Mocha.Test;
const Suite = Mocha.Suite;
const mocha = new Mocha();
for (let s in tests) {
  let suite = Suite.create(mocha.suite, s);
  tests[s].forEach((test) => {
    console.log('add test', test.name)
    suite.addTest(new Test(test.name), () => {
      expect(1+1).to.equal(2);
    });
  });
}
mocha.run();
```

The `tests` I'm running look like this:

```
{ todo: 
  [ { name: 'POST /todos',
      should: 'create a new todo',
      method: 'POST',
      endpoint: '/todos',
      body: [Object] } ] }
```

(though at this point my test is just trying to check a basic expect)

Based on the console.logs the iteration seems fine and it appears to be adding the tests, so I'm confident in the flow of operations, I just can't get any execution or errors.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to pass the test function to the `Test` constructor, not to `suite.addTest`. So change your code to add your tests like this:

```
suite.addTest(new Test(test.name, () => {
    expect(1+1).to.equal(2);
}));
```

Here is the entire code I'm running, adapted from your question:

```
import Mocha from 'mocha';
import { expect } from 'chai';
const Test = Mocha.Test;
const Suite = Mocha.Suite;
const mocha = new Mocha();

var tests = { todo:
  [ { name: 'POST /todos',
      should: 'create a new todo',
      method: 'POST',
      endpoint: '/todos',
      body: [Object] } ] };

for (let s in tests) {
  let suite = Suite.create(mocha.suite, s);
  tests[s].forEach((test) => {
      console.log('add test', test.name);
      suite.addTest(new Test(test.name, () => {
          expect(1+1).to.equal(2);
      }));
  });
}
mocha.run();
```

When I run the above with `node_modules/.bin/babel-node test.es6`, I get the output:

```
  todo
    ✓ POST /todos


  1 passing (5ms)
```

Comment: Now I'm getting output, but just `0 passing (2ms)`.

Comment: I've added the full code I'm running. There are things I did not mention like importing `chai` to get `expect`, which I consider tangential things but maybe you're having an issue there too.

Comment: Yeah, looks like an issue with a process I call beforehand. Seems to be working now, Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

It's critical to test your test system and make sure it deals with passing and failing tests and thrown exceptions.
Since folks are counting on a build process to warn them about errors, you must also set the exit code to a non-zero if anything failed.
Below is a test script (which you must invoke with `node test.js` rather than `mocha test.js`) which exercises all paths through your test suite:

```
const Mocha = require('mocha')
const expect = require('chai').expect
var testRunner = new Mocha()
var testSuite = Mocha.Suite.create(testRunner.suite, 'Dynamic tests')

var tests = [ // Define some tasks to add to test suite.
  { name: 'POST /todos', f: () => true }, //              Pass a test.
  { name: 'GET /nonos',  f: () => false }, //             Fail a test.
  { name: 'HEAD /hahas', f: () => { throw Error(0) } } // Throw an error.
]

tests.forEach(
  test =>
    // Create a test which value errors and caught exceptions.
    testSuite.addTest(new Mocha.Test(test.name, function () {
      expect(test.f()).to.be.true
    }))
)
var suiteRun = testRunner.run() //             Run the tests
process.on('exit', (code) => { //              and set exit code.
  process.exit(suiteRun.stats.failures > 0) // Non-zero exit indicates errors.
}) // Falling off end waits for Mocha events to finish.
```

---

Given that this is prominent in web searches for asynchronous mocha tests, I'll provide a couple more useful templates for folks to copy.

**Embedded execution:** The first directly adds tests which invoke an asynchronous faux-network call and check the result in a `.then`:

```
const Mocha = require('mocha')
const expect = require('chai').expect
var testRunner = new Mocha()
var testSuite = Mocha.Suite.create(testRunner.suite, 'Network tests')

var tests = [ // Define some long async tasks.
  { name: 'POST /todos', pass: true, wait: 3500, exception: null },
  { name: 'GET /nonos', pass: false, wait: 2500, exception: null },
  { name: 'HEAD /hahas', pass: true, wait: 1500, exception: 'no route to host' }
]

tests.forEach(
  test =>
    // Create a test which value errors and caught exceptions.
    testSuite.addTest(new Mocha.Test(test.name, function () {
      this.timeout(test.wait + 100) // so we can set waits above 2000ms
      return asynchStuff(test).then(asyncResult => {
        expect(asyncResult.pass).to.be.true
      }) // No .catch() needed because Mocha.Test() handles them.
    }))
)
var suiteRun = testRunner.run() //             Run the tests
process.on('exit', (code) => { //              and set exit code.
  process.exit(suiteRun.stats.failures > 0) // Non-zero exit indicates errors.
}) // Falling off end waits for Mocha events to finish.

function asynchStuff (test) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(() => {
//    console.log(test.name + ' on ' + test.endpoint + ': ' + test.wait + 'ms')
      if (test.exception)
        reject(Error(test.exception))
      resolve({name: test.name, pass: test.pass}) // only need name and pass
    }, test.wait)
  })
}
```

This code handles passing and failing data, reports exceptions, and exits with a non-zero status if there were errors. The output reports all expected problems and additionally whines about the test taking a like time (3.5s):

```
  Network tests
    ✓ POST /todos (3504ms)
    1) GET /nonos
    2) HEAD /hahas
  1 passing (8s)
  2 failing

  1) Network tests GET /nonos:
      AssertionError: expected false to be true
      + expected - actual    
      -false
      +true

  2) Network tests HEAD /hahas:
     Error: no route to host
```

---

**Delayed execution**: This approach invokes all of the slow tasks before populating and starting the the mocha test suite:

```
const Mocha = require('mocha')
const expect = require('chai').expect
var testRunner = new Mocha()
var testSuite = Mocha.Suite.create(testRunner.suite, 'Network tests')

var tests = [ // Define some long async tasks.
  { name: 'POST /todos', pass: true, wait: 3500, exception: null },
  { name: 'GET /nonos', pass: false, wait: 2500, exception: null },
  { name: 'HEAD /hahas', pass: true, wait: 1500, exception: 'no route to host' }
]

Promise.all(tests.map( // Wait for all async operations to finish.
  test => asynchStuff(test)
    .catch(e => { // Resolve caught errors so Promise.all() finishes.
      return {name: test.name, caughtError: e}
    })
)).then(testList => // When all are done,
  testList.map( //     for each result,
    asyncResult => //  test value errors and exceptions.
      testSuite.addTest(new Mocha.Test(asyncResult.name, function () {
        if (asyncResult.caughtError) { // Check test object for caught errors
          throw asyncResult.caughtError
        }
        expect(asyncResult.pass).to.be.true
      }))
  )
).then(x => { //                                 When all tests are created,
  var suiteRun = testRunner.run() //             run the tests
  process.on('exit', (code) => { //              and set exit code.
    process.exit(suiteRun.stats.failures > 0) // Non-zero exit indicates errors.
  })
})

function asynchStuff (test) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(() => {
//    console.log(test.name + ' on ' + test.endpoint + ': ' + test.wait + 'ms')
      if (test.exception)
        reject(Error(test.exception))
      resolve({name: test.name, pass: test.pass}) // only need name and pass
    }, test.wait)
  })
}
```

The output is the same except that mocha doesn't whine about the slow test and instead believes the tests took less than 10ms. The `Promise.all` waits for all the promises to resolve or reject *then* creates the tests to validate the results or report exceptions. This is a few lines longer than *Embedded execution* because it must:

1. Resolve exceptions so `Promise.all()` resolves.
2. Execute the tests in a final `Promise.all().then()`

Comments describing how folks pick which style to use could guide others. Share your wisdom!